# Running PHPUnit tests in Eclipse generates a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, php, eclipse, phpunit, eclipse-pdt

When I run PHPUnit tests in Eclipse PDT by right clicking on the test folder and selecting Run As > PHPUnit Testm

generates this error:

[image: PHPUnit Error in Eclipse]

I navigated to the Eclipse log file and found this text:

> eclipse.buildId=4.8.0.I20180611-0500
>
> java.version=10.0.2 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader
>
> constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework
>
> arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product Command-line
>
> arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
>
> org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
>
> This is a continuation of log file [obscured] Created Time: [obscured]
>
> org.eclipse.core.jobs Error An internal error occurred
>   during: "Launching phpunit-tests".
>
> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException     at
>   java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.php.phpunit.ui.launch.PHPUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.setEnvironmentVariables(PHPUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:341)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.php.phpunit.ui.launch.PHPUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(PHPUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:859)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)

A lot of the information I've found on the internet seems outdated.

Here's a little information about my environment:
PHP Version: 7.2.9
PHPUnit Version: 7.3.2
Platform: Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same issue with OpenJDK 11.0.3, Eclipse+PHP 2019-06 (4.1.12), using PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (in VirtualBox).

I'm using phpunit required by my project's composer.json with a local composer.phar in the same parent directory.

I had to not only set the Environment variable for port in the Run/Debug configuration asytaka did, but also explicitly set the Composer.phar that is in my workspace in order to finally get it to work. It's still a little flaky though in that right-clicking a different test file will auto-create a bogus (broken) debug/run configuration specifically for that file, so I just set the configuration to run all tests in my test directory.

Steps that worked:

1. Right-click Project->Run As->Run Configurations...
2. Delete any configurations that aren't working.
3. Right-click PHPUnit and select New Configuration
4. Under the PHPUnit tab, select "Use project's PHPUnit (Composer)"
5. Click the link that says "Click here to change the default phar."
6. For PHPUnit Phar: make sure you project's Composer.phar is selected in screen that comes up(Browse... but worked for me to select it).
7. Also vefify that Communication port: is set to 7478
8. Back in the configuration, on the Environment tab, also set a PHPUNIT_PORT variable to 7478 as yutaka posted.
9. I also put my test folder under "Run all tests in selected project, source folder or file" in the PHPUnit tab, and added the configuration to favorites for Run and Debug in the Common tab.

It still isn't perfect but at least it's running/debugging my tests in the IDE now.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was downgrading from **Java 10** to **Java 8**.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after adding `PHPUNIT_PORT`

[image]

Comment: Where you have added that PORT variable . i am not native to the language to screenshot